# What is wrong with the comparison a,b == 1,2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the following comparison of two variables return `(1, False, 2)`, instead of just `True`.

```
a = 1
b = 2
a,b == 1,2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Essentially this apparently weird behavior come from the fact that the right side of your expression is a tuple, the left side is not.

The expected result is achieved with this line, which compares a tuple with a tuple:

```
(a, b) == (1, 2)
```

Your expression instead is equivalent to:

```
(a, b == 1, 2)
```

Which is a tuple containing `a`, the comparison between `b` and `1`, and `2`.

You can see the different behavior using the `dis` module to check what python is doing:

```
import dis

dis.dis("a,b == 1,2")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             10 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             12 RETURN_VALUE

 dis.dis("(a,b) == (1,2)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 BUILD_TUPLE              2
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2))
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that in the first evaluation python is loading `a`, then is loading and `b` then loading the right side element of the comparison (`1`) and compare the last two loaded elements, then load the second right-element then build a tuple with the results of those operations and returns it.

In the second code instead python loads the left side (operations 0, 2 and 4) , loads the right side (operation 6), compare them and return the value.

Answer (score 10):

You need to explicitly compare the two tuples using parantheses:

```
a = 1
b = 2
print((a,b) == (1,2))  # True
```

Right now, you're creating the tuple `(a, b == 1, b)`. That evaluates to `(1, False, 2)`.